# Laravel trying to check if the user has relationship with post

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4, relationship

I have posts and these posts can be saved by users to read later. I created this relation and I can save or delete them easily. The problem is I can't check if the post is saved or not in frontend. Now I wrote some code to handle this but it doesn't seem to work. here is my controller code:

```
$articleFlag = 1; 
$userID = Auth::User()->id;

if (count($bestarticles) > 0) {
    foreach ($bestarticles as $bestarticle) {
        $saveddata = DB::table('savearticle')->where('user_id', $userID && 'article_id', $bestarticle);

        if (count($saveddata) > 0) {
            $articleFlag = 1;
        } else {
            $articleFlag = 2;
        }
    } //foeach endes here
} //first if endes here
```

and than I pass the `$articleFlag` to the view than checking it's value with an `if`
But the problem is, no matter what I do `if (count($bestarticles) > 0)` returns true and I get value 1 in view. 
Does anybody have any idea what I might be missing?

Here is my user controller relationshio:

```
   function savedarticle(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'savearticle', 'user_id', 
   'article_id');
   }
```

and here goes the functions that i use for saving and deleting:

```
    function savethearticle(Article $article){
     $this->savedarticle()->syncWithoutDetaching([$article->id]);
}
function removethearticle(Article $article){
     $this->savedarticle()->detach([$article->id]);
}
```

But there is nothing you need to worry about. I'm able to delete and add.

Or is there another way to check for existing relationship in view or a better way to check it in controller and pass into view?

I am using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: thanks for making it more readable. My braind does not work very well nowadays :/

Comment: Can you post your `User` and `Article` models, so we can see the relationships between them.

Comment: @fubar I added it. But I'm able to delete and add already, there is no problem with that. I;m not able to show save or delete button depending on if the user has saved the post already or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you have a `Collection` of `Article` models, and you're trying to determine whether it is related to the `User` or not.

If that's the case, I would suggest eager loading the `User` relation when you originally query the `Article` models. This has the advantage of using one query to load the relationship, rather than one per `Article`.

```
$userId = Auth::id();

$articles = Article::with(['savedarticle' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
    return $query->where('user_id' => $userId);
}])->get();
```

With this `Collection`, because we have loaded specifically the currently authenticated `User`, you can then proceed knowing that if the `savedarticle` relation has a `count` of `1`, that the `User` relation exists.

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    if ($article->savedarticle->count()) {
        // User has already saved article
    } else {
        // User has not saved article
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the sensitive way to go with, I will try it and will mark as right answer if it works

Answer (score 1):

Should you not be passing the id of bestarticle in the Where clause? Also, it requires a ->get() to actually fire the request off to the database and run the query.

```
 $saveddata = DB::table('savearticle')->where('user_id', $userID && 'article_id', $bestarticle);
```

Should be

```
 $saveddata = DB::table('savearticle')->where('user_id', $userID && 'article_id', $bestarticle->id)->get();
```

Comment: Still getting the value 1 in view which means the post is saved when it actuallt is not

Comment: I would add a ->get() to that line, then follow it with a dd($saveddata) to see why the count is greater than zero if you are expecting it to be zero. What is being returned?

Comment: yeah I tried that and it returns `Collection {#244 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: Because you were building the request, but not actually firing it. You need a get() or a first() to actually perform the get. I will update my answer.